# Regular expression to find floating point numbers inside square or round braces

Tags: python, regex, floating-point

I want to find the following patterns using regular expressions in python
`[3.000, 3.000]` or `(1.07,24.96)`

I need to find both square and round braces and 1 to 3 digit floating point numbers

```
regex="^[(\[]/\d+\.\d+/,/\d+\.\d+/[)\]]$"
```

The output is blank , no matches were found .

```
[(\[]- square/round braces
d+\.\d+/- decimal number
a comma and another decimal number
[)\]]- square/round closing
```

Comment: I recommend that you use a regex tester. There are several online ones.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import re
print(re.match(r"^[([]\d+\.\d+,\s*\d+\.\d+[)\]]$", '(1.07,24.96)'))
```

1. Use raw strings (`r"..."`) for regexes, it makes it more likely that your slashes and escaping will be correct.
2. `/` is not a character with any special meaning, I don't know why you had it there but get rid of them all.
3. Allow optional spaces after the comma with `\s*`.

Comment: Thank you for the solution. But it does not work if I pass a variable instead of an expression directly .
print(re.match(r"^[([]\d+\.\d+,\s*\d+\.\d+[)\]]$",line1)). This produces None as output. Line1 is a line from a file .I iterate over a file to find the match

Comment: @Ganga I'm guessing `line1` has trailing whitespace such as a newline. Try removing the `$` from the end of the pattern or matching against `line1.strip()`.